# Identity for the product of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Very easy question,

How to express $\prod_{i=0}^n \prod_{j=0}^i a_i a_j $ as a function of just one index?

Incidentally, where to find identities for product of sequences? There's a lot on identities for summation of sequences, but for product it is elusive.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what it means to express that "as a function of just one index". Maybe you could clarify with an example for $n=2$ or something...

Comment: For example, if $n=0$, then $\prod_{i=0}^0\prod_{j=0}^0a_i a_j=(\prod_{i=0}^0a_0)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You’re taking the product of all products of the form $a_ia_j$ with $0\le j\le i\le n$. For $0\le i\le n$, $a_i$ appears as a first factor $i+1$ times, once for each $j$ satisfying $0\le j\le i$. Each $a_j$ appears as a second factor $n-j+1$ times, once for each $i$ satisfying $j\le i\le n$. Thus, each $a_k$ appears a total of

$$(k+1)+(n-k+1)=n+2$$

times, and the product is simply $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^na_k^{n+2}$.

As an example, for $n=2$ you have

$$\prod_{i=0}^2\prod_{j=0}^ia_ia_j=\big(a_0^2\big)\big((a_1a_0)(a_1^2)\big)\big((a_2a_0)(a_2a_1)(a_2^2)\big)=(a_0a_1a_2)^4\;.$$

Comment: For $n=1$, why is it not simply $a_0^2*a_1*(a_0a_1)$?

Comment: @user2820579: For $n=1$ it’s $$\big(a_0^2\big)\big((a_1a_0)(a_1)^2\big)=(a_0a_1)^3\;.$$ The $i=j=1$ factor is $a_1^2$, not $a_1$.